# How do I read a vCard?

Tags: contacts, vcard

so someone tells me i need to call a few people.  they send me a vCard called contacts.vcf.  i import it.  i open my phone app and start to dial, but wait...i don't know their names.

How do i look up a recent vCard on my phone?  How do i know who's contact i've been sent?  when i navigate to a .vcf file, i can't open it.  all i can do is import it.  polaris office won't import/open it.  is there an android txt editor i can use to peruse a vCard?

yours truly,
Confused by vCards
Note 3, kit kat

Comment: Have you tried opening the vCard using the default Contacts app?

Comment: I think winrar or 7zip will be able to show you the insides of a vcard file. just try it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to open a vCard file in any basic editor. Navigate using a file manager to open up the vcard in a text editor. It should display the contents.

Answer (score 1):

Use a text editor to open the VCF file. It should look like this:

```
BEGIN:VCARD

VERSION:2.1

FN:****FIRST NAME******

N:******NAME*******;;;;

TEL;VOICE;PREF:********NUMBER********

END:VCARD
```

**Replace** all stars with the data's name that I provided between them.

You may use ES File Explorer to open VCF file as text.

Answer (score 1):

I think this app, [Contacts VCF](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=by.androld.contactsvcf) should do what you want. Shows the list of contacts inside a .vcf file.

> The application allows you to open files with the extension of import
>   contacts .vcf (vCard) as a phone book to add and edit the contacts,
>   make calls. It can be used as an alternative to contacts Android. Get
>   a copy of all the contacts from the device easily. Print out your
>   contacts using the export to .txt or web page Was **added inspector for
>   the files .vcf**

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Android phone you have, there's another way to open the .vcf file. Press and hold down the message.  A message options will appear.  Forward the message to someone who has an update Andriod phone. In my case I forward the message to my daughter. I have her hand me down phone Galaxy S and she has the Galaxy 5 (five).

Comment: So what should she do with the forwarded message? You seem to have given half of the instructions.